# Doing a chemistry experiment or work on a chemistry experiment?

Tags: word-choice

`Doing a chemistry experiment` or `working on a chemistry experiment`?

Which one is correct? Did some google search but found nothing related. Should I use `do` or `work on`?

Answer (score 6):

Depends on what you want to say. "Doing" a chemistry experiment feels a little more final. You sit down, you do it, and you're done. "Working on" a chemistry experiment feels more ongoing, where you make progress on it but you don't finish. So I would use "do" if it's a short experiment that you're going to do all at once, and "working on" if you are working on getting it ready and setting it up, or if it's a long experiment that will take a day or longer.

Answer (score 6):

I would offer a third alternative, particularly as it relates to an experiment:

```
"Conducting a chemistry experiment...."
```

There is a particular relationship between an *experiment* and carrying it out, conveyed by "conducting." An *experiment* refers essentially to observing the results of an orchestrated series of steps or processes, and the word "conducting" is commonly used in this context. `"Performing"` is also a good alternative.

Comment: Or *carry out* an experiment. OP's *do* sounds more like something kids do in school *(We did boring English for an hour, but then it was Chemistry, where we did an exciting experiment)*.